# selecting average value from group of same with max on another for several columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, select

I was struggling to select an average value for a group of same fix_ids values with max value on another column eventually someone helped me and I ended up with this code

```
select fix_id
     , timestamp
     , avg(age)
  from t
 where age > 0 
   and timestamp = 
  (select max(t2.timestamp) 
    from t t2 
   where t2.fix_id = t.fix_id)
group by fix_id;
```

This does exactly what it supposed, however, I need to select the same way avg value for several columns and I'm wondering if there is a way to do it in one query. I could do

```
avg(age),avg(height)
```

But since I skipped rows with 0 values for age column height will be missing those rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select fix_id, timestamp,
       avg(case when age > 0 then age end) as avg_age,
       avg(height) as avg_height
from t
where timestamp = (select max(t2.timestamp) from t t2 where t2.fix_id = t.fix_id)
group by fix_id;
```